# How do I set a variable to a index of a list?

Tags: python, list

```
l = [1,2,4]

for i in range(3):
    a = l[i]
```

im tryihng to do that above but it isn't working and it says
'builtin_function_or_method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. can anyone say why this is and tell me how to fix this
edit:There was something earlier in the code before this and it was because i was doing .lower and not .lower() sorry guys

Comment: did you mean `for i in range(3):`? with the colon at the end?

Comment: Note that lists are indexed starting at `0`, so even with that change you would have gotten an `IndexError` when i=2.

Comment: In addition to what @GreenCloakGuy noted, `l` only has two items in it and `range(3)` is too large.

Comment: @JoySingh Even if someone is new to Python they should be able to copy and paste the code they used. The code presented here won't give the error that is mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JoySingh meh's answer doesn't answer the question... the question was 'how do I set a variable to a index of a list' which isn't answered in meh's answer until the edit. as for the error, OP simply made the mistake of typing out the code instead of pasting it in (note to OP that you should always paste the code you use into a SO question), resulting in the error not being reproducible.

Comment: @JoySingh This is not a quiz. Guessing the real code is not want I want to do here. If I take the code as it is I get `SyntaxError`. If I add the missing `:` I get `IndexError`. So can anyone answer the question why this code delivers 'builtin_function_or_method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain what your code does before solving it. **Edit available at the bottom of the answer**

```
for i in range(3):
   a = l[i]
```

What this does is creates a "range" of numbers from 0 to 2, however its supposed to go from 1 (or 0) to 3. Why? Computers have been trained to start counting from 0 instead of 1 like a normal human and subsequently they are 1 less. (This is a simplified one, there's a longer one that you'll learn over time)
Now your 2nd line of code assigns the variable a the value of one of the items in the list l. Let's look at what value 'a' would be assigned during this time

```
1 (1st item)
2 (2nd item)
IndexError: Out of range error (there is no 3rd item)
```

So how do you solve this? One way is to add more items to your list l.
So let's then add 2 more items into l (3 and 4)
This is our variable l now

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here's our output now

```
1 (1st item)
2 (2nd item)
3 (3rd item)
```

As you noticed, it skips the 4th item since we specified to only iterate over 3 items in the list. If you wanted to "iterate over a list" look no further!.

Observe

```
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

This creates a for loop that goes over each item in the list l one by one from start to finish that allows you to see the current item in the variable i! In our code, it simply prints the variable i each time the for loop goes to the next item in the list.

```
1
2
3 
4
```

And simply stops once it reaches the end!
Don't worry, we've all been there while learning code :)

UPDATE: Based on what you were saying, I'm assuming if you wanted to assign the variable a the 2nd place in the list 'l' you would use

```
a = l[1]
```

Yes to get the 2nd place you need to type 1. The same goes for accessing the 1st item, you change the l[1] with l[0]. This is because computers count from 0 instead of human's traditionally counting from 1

Answer (score 0):

the code you wrote isn't even syntactically correct.

```py
l = [1,2]

for i in range(len(l)):
    # you had no colon, so the first error you should have gotten is a syntax error.
    # the second error you would have gotten is a value error, because you try to set 'a' to values
    # that don't exist. a more dynamic way to do it anyways is to cycle through the
    # length of the list.
    a = l[i]
```

im not sure why you want to do this, as it will result in `a = 2`. staying true to your question, the only reasonable way to do what you're asking is something as easy as this.

```py
a = l[2] # or whatever index you're trying to get
```

you're method, even if it compiled correctly, would not have accomplished what you say you want.

as mentioned by 'meh' and 'shriakhilc', keep in mind that indexing starts at 0, so the list `l` would only have indexes of 0 and 1.

Comment: This code is a very complicated way of iterating over a loop

Comment: it really isn't but if you would like to substitute `for i in range(len(l))` with `for i in l` then be my guest, the rest of it is perfectly reasonable

Comment: @DavyJonesStockings Oh yes, it is. And it is what is called _unpythonic_.

Comment: @Matthias in an actual script you probably wouldn't assign the list index to the variable, assuming you aren't changing the list. i simply provided an answer to the question.

Comment: @Matthias The question literally asks how to use an **index** of a list. `For i in l:` might be more pythonic but it does not answer the question.